# Create Block with setTagName nested

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, link

I have this code:

```
 $link = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text_tag')
        ->setTagName('a')
        ->setTagParams(array(
            'href'  => '#',
            'class' => 'link',
        ))
        ->setTagContents($text)
   ;
```

that creates a link `<a href="#" class"link"></a>`

how do I create a span element inside this type?

```
<a href="#" class"link"><span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `Mage_Core_Block_Text_Tag` class, I guess that the fastest (not the most elegant...) way to do that is :

```
$link = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text_tag')
    ->setTagName('a')
    ->setTagParams(array(
        'href'  => '#',
        'class' => 'link',
    ))
    ->setTagContents('<span>'.$text.'</span>')
;
```